# Xcode>Instruments>Automation>Mac: is there a way to use regular expression within Automation in Instruments

Tags: xcode-instruments

I am totally new to Instruments>Automation. Trying to test the internal app using Automation in Instruments.

Here is my problem:
Our app has the UI cells generated on the fly. There is no way to predict how many cells will be created and what name they will have. But, all of them will contain a certain string (like "Courses"). The question is - How, using Automation, find out if particular cell contain that string in its name?

Answer (score 0):

You are able to get total cells count simply using "length" property.

```
var cellsCount = <YourUIATableViewObject>.cells().length;
UIALogger.logMessage("total cells count = " + cellCount);
```

After that you will be able to get cell properties and operate with them:

```
for (var i = 0; i < cellsCount; i ++)
{
     var cellValue = <YourUIATableViewObject>.cells()[i].value();
     var cellName = <YourUIATableViewObject>.cells()[i].name();
     UIALogger.logMessage("Cell #"+i+" properties: cellValue ="+cellValue+"; cellName ="+cellName);

     //Try to use match() or search() functions to find what you need.
     if ( cellName.search("Courses") != -1 )
     //if (cellValue.search("Courses") != -1 )
     {
          UIAlogger.logMessage("Cell #"+i+" contains 'Courses'");
     }
     else
     {
          UIAlogger.logMessage("Cell #"+i+" does not contain 'Courses'");
     }
}
```

This [JavaScript tutorial](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String) will help you: